# How to disable eslint type errors in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I don't use typescript but i have type errors. I want to ignore type errors. But i couldn't disable them. Does anybody have idea?

Examples:
[image]

[image]

And this is my package.json:
[image]

Comment: Those messages _are_ from TypeScript, not the linter.

Comment: So, what should I do? I don't want use typescript

Comment: Go to your settings in VSCode (CTRL+,), search for "validation", click the "Typescript" option in the menu, and disable validation for JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, its worked, but does it affect another rules like unused variables vb.?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but from your screenshot it seems you are using VSCode as your IDE.
If you just want to stop these errors from showing up in the IDE, adding these overrides in your [user/workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) should help:-

```
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
"javascript.validate.enable": false,
```

Also, it looks like a `create-react-app` scaffolded project, if you do not intend to use Typescript, it would be ideal to scaffold the project again without it, if that is still an option!

Answer (score -1):

I myself found the solution from here Edit .env:

DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true

Or in package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build",
    "test": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts test"
  }
}
```

Comment: But this affects all eslint rules, i like eslint. I only need solution for this problem

Comment: You can stop using @ts-ignore

Or you can disable the eslint rule. Add that in your eslint config (.eslintrc or equivalent)
...
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": "off"
  }
...
EDIT: If you are using @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin version 2.18 or higher, the rule is called ban-ts-comment and you need to add

"@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off"